# Is there any pre-existing plugin to track and block IPs with suspicious activity on my site?

Tags: plugins, security, hacked

The image below shows a recent (failed) attempt to crack my Wordpress install. It's easy for me to look at that and see what they were doing, but is there a plugin that exists that monitors this data and can catch events like this? Especially for something as blatant as this, I would like to block the IPs, but it's not exactly practical for me to sit watching IP activity 24/7.

Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/ which blocks IPs when login attempts exceed set limit you set.

> Limit Login Attempts blocks an Internet address from making further
>   attempts after a specified limit on retries is reached, making a
>   brute-force attack difficult or impossible.

If you're on a host where you can install and run root code, look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/fail2ban/

> "Fail2Ban monitors log files like /var/log/pwdfail or
>   /var/log/apache/error_log and bans failure-prone addresses. It updates
>   firewall rules to reject the IP address or executes user defined
>   commands."